# Pandas : transform a column containing list of strings to new columns for each value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a column containing a list of values to a new set of columns, one for each value over all rows of that column.

For example given :

```
index    cat
0       ['a','b']
1       ['c','a','d']
2       ['e','b','c']
```

I'd like to get :

```
index    a       b       c        d         e
0        1       1       0        0         0
1        1       0       1        1         0
2        0       1       1        0         1
```

Could you help me and point me in the right direction?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#df=df.set_index('index') #if index is a column
d=df.explode('cat')
new_df=pd.crosstab(d.index,d.cat)
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
cat    a  b  c  d  e
row_0               
0      1  1  0  0  0
1      1  0  1  1  0
2      0  1  1  0  1
```

---

```
print(df)
         cat
0     [a, b]
1  [c, a, d]
2  [e, b, c]
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is that row_0 coming from?

Comment: I think it's due to the name of the index, you can use: `pd.crosstab(df.index,df.YEAR,rownames=['myrowname'])` to change the name or `new_df.rename_axis(index=None)` to remove it! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: Yea, should have read the doc before typing :d Well thanks a lot. I saw that the question got downvoted and see you have quite some rep, any clue on how to improve the question?

Comment: You're welcome :) I really don't understand why this question was rejected, I think it's quite clear and simple to understand. I already  upvote:)